# how to use arry element as array name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

im practicing javascript and i have arrays (more than 10) which have strings in it
var p = ["one","two","three","four"];
var q = [//somthing here]

and another array which is created by a function which select n store some array names for further actions

var m = ["p","q","r","s"];

how can i use element of array m as the varable/array name like:

```
<button onclick="testArrays(dest, m[0])">desti</button>
```

must have to work like this

```
<button onclick="testArrays(dest, p)">desti</button>
```

all i want to say that how can i use m[0] as a variable

**im not using objects**

Comment: The answer is to use an object with a `name -> array` mapping. If the runtime behavior of your code depends on variable names, then you are likely doing something wrong.

Comment: @FelixKling , why are you marking this question as a duplicate i m not using objects here and ive already searched the question you are seggesting. please just solve my problem , i m just begginer in javascript

Comment: The linked question contains all possible solutions to this problem. And the point is at you *should* be using an object instead. If you think you should not, then you should explain your use case in more detail. But again, the linked question pretty much covers all possible solutions.

Comment: We know you're not using objects. That's the point. You should be. If you actually heed the advice given, you'll find that objects are the proper solution in JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a variable where? If it's a property of an object you can use `object[m[0]]`

And if it's on the global scope you can use the `window` object `window[m[0]]`. If it's a variable inside a function you should rethink your approach. There is a way that starts with e and ends with val and you should never, ever use it.

Comment: can you show me please how with eval

Comment: `eval(m[0])` would return your `p` variable, but you should never ever use this in an actual real-world application. It's a horrible practice and if you HAVE to use it, you've taken the wrong approach to your problem.

Comment: its not working when i m printing it using the function it says [object HTMLHtmlElement]

Comment: and usin window[] its saying undefined

Comment: Then `p` in your scope is a html element and not an array. With the code you posted, it works. http://jsfiddle.net/506x1wuj/ But please learn to code the proper way instead.